# How to remove a particular pattern of string from regex match? Can't use XML parser it will recognise only good XML tags

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regexp pattern /[\w]+=[\w" :]+/ to remove the attributes like /id=""/ in the xml tags, I tried to keep this pattern as generic as possible, but this pattern removes the /href="https:/ attribute as well which I don't want to remove from the xml tags

Regex pattern /[\w]+=[\w" :]+/

Source xml string is,

```
<table id="this is id">
<tr id="this tr id">
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<div id="this is div id"><span id="div Class:a">this is span 
text</span></div>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm expecting this o/p,

```
<table >
<tr >
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<div ><span >this is span text</span></div>
</tr>
</table>
```

but I'm getting this o/p,

```
<table >
<tr >
<a //www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<div ><span >this is span text</span></div>
</tr>
</table>
```

The above above is available in this link [My RegEx pattern to remove id attribute](https://regex101.com/r/u82FEo/1)

Comment: Why not use a `XML/HTML` parser and remove the attributes you don't

Comment: I'm getting the source XML text with incomplete tags so XML parser won't work, here I'm trying to clean the unwanted texts using regexp first before sending it to XML parser

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Use a negative look-ahead assertion

**Details**

You can start your regular expression with a negative look-ahead assertion that will exclude the pattern you don't want matched:

```
(?!href)\b[\w]+=[\w" :]+
```

And if there were two or more attributes you wanted to exclude, you would list them with an "or" in between:

```
(?!href|exclude_this_too)\b[\w]+=[\w" :]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u82FEo/2), extended from yours

Please note the `\b` I also added: it says `[\w]+` must be at the start of a word. This is important, otherwise it matches `ref=...` just leaving out the `h`, which is not what you want.